# A trigger button for date calender element selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im currently using jquery date calender but my question applies to any date calender https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
is there a way i  can have an external button which when clicked select specific first element in a given calendar row/column (say row 1)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question with a code example or something you have tried. Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: please you don't have to JUDGE my question if you don't understand it

Comment: I placed no judgements upon your post. If that's the way you want to get help, that's fine by me. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code snippet. 
Is this the one that you are trying to achieve

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker();
  $("#button1").bind('click', click);
});

function click() {
  $('#date').datepicker('show')
  $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tr:first").addClass('red');
}
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">date

<input type="text" id="date" />

<input type="button" id="button1" value="click" />
```